# Do I need PDA to send SOL to another account?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, pda, transfer, sol

I'm struggling to send SOL to another address(fixed one when initialize) on Rust level along logging the sender's account address on the program.

Do I need PDA for this?
Also I have to log the sender's account address on the program.

I tried to write some code by investigating code example.
Please let me know if this would work. :)

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

declare_id!("Fg6PaFpoGXkYsidMpWTK6W2BeZ7FEfcYkg476zPFsLnS");

#[program]
pub mod transfer_sol {
    use super::*;
    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> ProgramResult {
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn buy_ticket(ctx: Context<BuyTicket>, amount: u64) -> Result <()> {
        let base_account = &mut ctx.accounts.base_account;
        let user = &mut ctx.accounts.user;

        // Transfer Sol
        let transfer_sol = transfer(
            &ctx.accounts.user.key(),
            base_account.dest,
            amount
        );

        invoke(
            &transfer_sol,
            &[
                *user.to_account_info(),
                ctx.accounts.dest.to_account_info(),
                ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
            ],
        )?;

        base_account.users.push(*user.to_account_info().key);

        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    user: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = user,
        space = 8 + 100,
        seeds = [b"tickets".as_ref()],
        bump
    )]
    base_account: Account<'info, BaseAccount>,
    system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct BuyTicket<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub base_account: Account<'info, BaseAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct BaseAccount {
    pub users: Vec<PublicKey>,
    pub dest: PublicKey
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the user's wallet is a signer in the instruction, your example will work!  You can propagate their signature down to any other program, which is what you're doing with the `invoke` into the system program's transfer instruction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
`What do you mean by propagate their signature down to any other program?`

Comment: If I sign your instruction, I can also be a signer for any CPI that you call from your instruction.  So if your instruction calls `transfer` to move my lamports, that's fine.  If your instruction withdraws from my stake account, that's also OK.  You can read more about it at https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/calling-between-programs#instructions-that-require-privileges

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer is that you don't need a PDA to transfer Solana from one account to another.

If your goal is to transfer Solana from a system program owned account to another account (owned by any program), then you just need to pass in the signature of the sender account. That signature could come from a PDA or a key pair private key.